# saveAsTextFile gives errors

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark

I tried to save a file as text in spark environment in python and I get this error as below. I am trying to save the output of a simple program.

lines.saveAsTextFile("outputDirectory");

error: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4
\winutils\bin\winutils.exe": CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not
compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's sys
tem information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version o
f the program, and then contact the software publisher

Comment: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-convert-existing-data-into-parquet/ -- Add hadoop bin utils (HADOOP_HOME) as environment variable to your path when you’re running this in windows and this exception won’t happen.

Comment: Thanks Alan I did this and still run into this exception. I did add HADOOP_PATH in environment variables and downloaded the version of 32 bit which fits my machine.